# "Pushes sent 0" in parse dashboard for android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am trying to send push notifications from parse to android. While sending it from browser the calculations of the devices are being shown properly. But "Pushes sent 0" is being displayed in the browser.

I register for notifications in Application class

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
        } else {
            Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
        }
    }
});
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

I have also created the `Receiver` in my android project

```
public class PushMessageBroadcast extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("The push","open");
    }

    @Override
    protected Notification getNotification(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getNotification(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushDismiss(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPushDismiss(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //here You can handle push before appearing into status e.g if you want to stop it.
        super.onPushReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

I have also done the changes in manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receivers.PushMessageBroadcast "
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Do I need to change any settings in parse? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try sending the notification to all devices instead of to a specific channel and see if that works

Comment: It will always display as 0 for a couple of minutes. If after sending push notifications you wait for a while and then refresh, it should update to the correct number of devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited answer**

After @lochana-tejas comment I realized that my answer was not correct because I disabled again in Google Developer console "Cloud Messaging for Android" and my device had received the notification anyway.

So the first thing you need to control is that in **Parse Dashboard** you have the class **Installation** and this class have one or more devices registered. If you don't have this class or is empty “Pushes sent" will be 0.

[image]

I copy my code here so you can compare

```
  public static void registerParse(Context context) {
        Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);

        Parse.initialize(context, PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(PARSE_CHANNEL, new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("com.parse.push", "Successfully subscribed to Parse!");
                } else {
                    Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //This is the user that will be inserted in "Installation class"
    public static void subscribeWithUser(String user) {
        ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();

        installation.put("user", user);

        installation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.e("subscribeWithUser", "User subscribed successfully!!", e);
                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("subscribeWithUser", "Error to save user", e);
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

My manifest is this

```
        <!-- Added for Parse push notifications -->

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.CustomPushReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.parse.starter" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: you mean we do not want to add the gcm registration coding but need to create the project in google console?

Comment: @LochanaTejas you were right. It wasn't necessary enable API in Google Developer console so I changed all my answer

Comment: yes now the edited answer is correct. Not need to enable GCM in console or no need of adding GCM code in our Android. But I still created the project and have my senderID with me but doing nothing. Need to make changes oly in the manifest and register pushes to an activity which is used to handle notification once received

Comment: I accept this answer also including my above comment