# Port 8253 with parse pushnotifications android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have been trying with parse Push notifications and also posted a question here
  ["Pushes sent 0" in parse dashboard for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432783/pushes-sent-0-in-parse-dashboard-for-android)
I read few more SO answers 
 [Parse Push Notification not work on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592617/parse-push-notification-not-work-on-android)
 [Parse Push Notification not work on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592617/parse-push-notification-not-work-on-android)

It seems like I have to try it with signed apk and  open port 8253.

Is this really needed.

I also tried with signed apk but no results.

Can any one let me know how to open port 8253 in my mobile?